# Replace NULL with blank value OS400

Tags: sql, null

I am trying to get my result set to return a blank rather than NULL, I have tried COALESCE but just cannot seem to get this to work, here is that section of my query:

CASE HHHCRIN
WHEN 'Y' THEN HHHINVN ELSE ''
END AS "Credit Memo Document Number",

Answer (score 0):

You have to start with the COALESCE command first to list your nulls, then include a CASE command to your resulting COALESCE new column to replace your nulls with blanks

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE works left to right and returns you the first non null thing encountered in that order;

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(name,address,'unknown value')
FROM Person
```

"If name is null, try address, if address is null, try 'unknown value' - and 'unknown value' is definitely not null"

For the following table:

```
Name,Address,  COALESCE returns
John,The Road, John
John,NULL,     John
NULL,The Road, The Road
NULL,NULL,     unknown value
```